# Spatial join crashes when called from script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spatial, geopandas

I have a geopandas spatial join statement that runs fine when performing from Jupyter Notebook.
However, when called from a windows task scheduler script (pointing to a `.bat` file every morning at 07:00) the logfile I create stops giving output precisely before the call to spatial join.

```
geodf = geodf[geodf.geometry.notnull()]
print(len(geodf) - before, 'geometries were dropped that had null values')

# spatial join the dataframe with the airspace will 'place' the points in the right airspace
df3 = geodf.sjoin(AirspaceNL, how='left' )
print('spatial join done with AirspaceNL')
```

The statement `geodf = geodf[geodf.geometry.notnull()]` is executed without problems. I can read the 'geometries were dropped ...' etc. in the logfile. Then it stops. Apparently the spatial join of the next statement is the problem? Note that when run directly from Jupyter Notebook, all is fine.

Well... not *all* is fine. In Jupyter Notebook, I get the following warning with pink background:

```
C:\Users\bruggenj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:1204: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cast
  if not (lk == lk.astype(rk.dtype))[~np.isnan(lk)].all():
```

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: I looked into the package merge.py and found following source code in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed my last hunch was correct. The version of GeoPandas running on this other machine was out of date and did not have `sjoin` as an attrtibute. Updating the package with `pip install -U geopandas` in a Conda command window on the computer that runs my script solved it.

Sorry for bothering you with my stupidity...

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the referenced package `merge.py` and found following source code in

`def _maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self) -> None:`

```
                elif is_integer_dtype(rk.dtype) and is_float_dtype(lk.dtype):
                    if not (lk == lk.astype(rk.dtype))[~np.isnan(lk)].all():
                        warnings.warn(
                            "You are merging on int and float "
                            "columns where the float values "
                            "are not equal to their int representation.",
                            UserWarning,
                        )
```

Still understand nothing of it, except that I am apparently (and unknowingly) merging int and float??

(And why is the full warning not displayed in my Jupyter Notebook?)

I must admit I am quite lost. Any help/clue/suggestion welcome.

Comment: I suspect that the version of Geopandas on the machine where my code runs is not up to date and does not have the 'sjoin' attribute.